# Ruby on Rails 3: How to create a 12 hour (with AM/PM) time select element?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

From what I can tell by looking in the Rails source code, it looks like all the methods are there. I just can't figure out how to call `time_select` with the right options to enable 12 hour and add a AM/PM select element. What options do I need pass in order to create this?

Here are a few things that I've tried:

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :created_at %><br />
    <%= f.time_select :created_at, :ampm => true              #didnt do anything %>
    <%= time_select('post', 'created_at', { :ampm => true })  #also didnt do anything %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4):

`time_select("post", "written_on", {:ampm => true})`

**Update**
You need to update your Rails version. The ampm selector was added in [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/a869382a9fa241f72a7a73d4a9738531c4c37ba5)

> commit a869382a9fa241f72a7a73d4a9738531c4c37ba5 Author: Aditya Sanghi
>    Date:   Fri Apr 29 01:49:45 2011 +0530
>
> ```
> Allow AM/PM in datetime selectors
> ```

which is not in 3.0.x. Sorry.

Comment: In other words, this is coming in Rails 3.1? Or... How can I update to this version?

Comment: I realized I was on 3.0.7, so I upgraded to 3.0.9, but that still didn't seem to work. I can't tell what version of Rails this commit would have been merged into.

Comment: Yes it is in 3.1.beta. Sorry for the wild goose chase, I should have checked before posting.